# Generate a data uri small text file from two forms inputs with regex validation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a webpage tool that will generate a text connection file from two forms input

First form is a for database id, will be pasted and will have to match regex `^(\w{8})-(\w{4})-(\w{4})-(\w{4})-(\w{12})$`
Second form will be table name, and must not be empty. The tool doesn't know what are the possible values.

Ideally any time forms input are valid (without waiting for submit click so on keyup or input I believe), we should have a href link below the form which would be a data uri generating the txt file itself connect.txt "connect to `Tablename` from `databaseid`" (imaginary language)

I found some fiddles I tried to mix/adapt without success, mainly:

https://jsfiddle.net/fma1hyoL/4/ for dynamic text generation with validation

https://jsfiddle.net/wtp5a0o8/1/ for generating the file uri

beginner in html and javascript, could you point me in the right direction?

also, any bad practice to avoid regarding such functionnalities?

Thanks and regards

Comment: It would be the txt file itself connect.txt "connect to Tablename from databaseid"

Comment: ***be a data uri generating the txt file itself connect.txt*** Is this connect.txt created on server side and stored on the server system?

Comment: created on the user browser, not server. something like `data:application/vndoasisopendocumentchart,select%20database%20name` with a file extension and a name

Comment: or more: `href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI` like in https://jsfiddle.net/wtp5a0o8/1/

Comment: To clarify, you want to generate a text file based on two form inputs - database name and table name. This should happen on a button click. The generated file should contain string in format "connect to tablename from dbname". Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

found it thanks to Dan:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Romain</title>
   <style>
      label {
         display: block;
      }

      input {
         padding: 1.2em;
         width: 25em;
      }

      input:required:invalid,
      input:focus:invalid {
         background-color: #faa;
      }

      #result {
         border: 1px solid #333;
         font-family: monospace;
         padding: 1em;
         display: none;
      }

      #result.isVisible {
         display: inherit;
      }

   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form">
      <p>
         <label>
            Database id
            <input
               required
               id="dbField"
               type="text"
               pattern="(\w{8})-(\w{4})-(\w{4})-(\w{4})-(\w{12})"
               placeholder="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            />
         </label>
      </p>
      <p>
         <label>
            Table name
            <input
               required
               id="tableField"
               type="text"
               placeholder=""
               value=""
            />
         </label>
      </p>
   </form>
   <div id="result" class="">
      <a
         id="resultLink"
         href="#"
         target = "_blank"
         download = "myFile.txt"
      ></a>
   </div>
   <script>
      const form = document.getElementById('form');
      const dbField = document.getElementById('dbField');
      const tableField = document.getElementById('tableField');
      const result = document.getElementById('result');
      const resultLink = document.getElementById('resultLink');
      const resultButton = document.getElementById('resultButton');

      // Callback: Update #result if form fields are valid
      const update = function(event){
         if (
            !dbField.checkValidity()
            || !tableField.checkValidity()
         ){
            // Hide result
            result.classList.remove('isVisible');
            return;
         };

         // Update link text & href
         result.classList.add('isVisible');
         resultLink.innerHTML = getOutputText();
         resultLink.href = `data:attachment/text,${encodeURI(getOutputText())}`;
      }

      // Return the output text from the form field values
      const getOutputText = function(){
         return `connect to ${tableField.value} from ${dbField.value}`;
      }

      // Call update() on form keyup events
      form.addEventListener('keyup', update);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```